# How to move a bunch of files in their own new folder

Tags: bash, files, mv

I have a list of files in a folder:

```
./file1.ext
./file2.ext2
./file3.ext
```

I want to move all these files in their own new folder with their related name, like:

```
./file1/file1.ext
./file2/file2.ext2
./file3/file3.ext
```

Is there a way to do so in very few commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop to do so :

```
for f in *; do
    [ ! -d "${f%.*}" ] && mkdir "${f%.*}/"
    mv "$f" "${f%.*}/"
done
```

This will create and move everything in your current directory.

`${f%.*}` take the trailing extension. I also use it to verify if the directory already exist in case you have multiple file like `file1.ext` and `file1.ext1`.

In case you have a `file1` this script will not work for any file begining with `file1`

Comment: That's perfect!